# Flush data from Historical Node Memory to Deep Storage

Tags: druid

I had initially setup a druid cluster with  2 historical nodes with 30gb memory each. 2 middle manager nodes, one node with coordinator and overlord running, 1 broker node.

After successfully running it for 3-4weeks, I saw that my tasks were staying in the running state even after the window period. I then happened to add one more historical node with same configuration, this resulted in my tasks working fine again.
What this meant was all the data ingested to druid is going to memory and I will have to keep on adding historical nodes.

Is there a way to flush some of the data from memory to deep storage and it should get loaded into memory whenever a query is fired against that set of data?
Each of my historical node is of 30GB RAM. Configs :

druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes=1073741824

druid.segmentCache.locations=[{"path":"var/druid/segment-cache","maxSize":32212254720}]

druid.port=7080

druid.service=druid/historical

druid.server.maxSize=100000000000

druid.server.http.numThreads=50

druid.processing.numThreads=5
druid.query.groupBy.maxResults=10000000

druid.query.groupBy.maxOnDiskStorage=10737418240

Comment: It depends on the druid configuration for historical nodes, add the configurations in your questions, than I may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @mdeora. I have added the configs for historical node in the question.

Comment: Please add your data size too.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to calculate that but in the segment-cache directory I can disk space of 49G being used on each of the 4 historical nodes. I am currently adding one node per week.

Comment: I don't think its a memory or disk space issue, What is  "druid.worker.capacity" set? and how many cpu cores assigned are per historical?

Comment: worker capacity is set to 4. each historical node has 8 CPUs. I am not facing problem in creating a job. Job gets created but it stays in running state even after its window gets over. When I add another historical node, then it moves to success state. My consecutive jobs run fine for couple of days and I again end up at same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as mentioned in the question, my problem was that I had to launch a new node every few days not sure why. The root cause was the disk space on each historical node.
Essentially, even if druid pushes data to deep storage, it also keeps all the data locally on the historical nodes too.
So you can only store data equal to sum of 'druid.server.maxSize' config in all the historical nodes. 
If you don't wish to scale horizontally, you can increase the disk of historical nodes and increase the value of this config and restart the historical nodes.